# C- will locally declared String be accessible outside function call?

Tags: c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Trouble with returning a string from function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5655853/trouble-with-returning-a-string-from-function)
>   [Can a local variable’s memory be accessed outside its scope?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6441218/can-a-local-variables-memory-be-accessed-outside-its-scope)

I'm trying to use a function to modify the value of a String pointer. I declared a struct called someStruct, and one of the fields is a pointer to a string, named 'valu'. Here's what I did:

```
void func(char* nvalue,someStruct* container){
    char temp[strlen(nvalue+1);
    temp=strcpy(temp,nvalue);
    container->valu=temp;
    return;
```

Will this function modify the value of the container to be nvalue? If not, how can I do it? I'm really not good with C so any help would be nice! Thank you

Comment: `temp=strcpy(temp,nvalue);` isn't legal and you're missing a `]` on the line above for starters.

Comment: `container->valu=temp;` This is wrong as `temp` is a local array and you are assigning it to a pointer and expect it to be valid outside the function. This is undefined behaviour in C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `tmp` is a local variable, accessing to `container->value` outside of the function is an undefined behavior. However, it is possible to use dynamic allocation to control the lifetime of your variable.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char **p = &container->value;

*p = malloc(strlen(nvalue) + 1);

if (*p != NULL)
{
  strcpy(*p, nvalue);
}
```

Comment: What does it mean to control the lifetime of the variable? If I use malloc I have to free the memory somewhere else right? Is that what you meant? Or does it get automatically freed?

Comment: @user1926344: No, `container->value` won't be automatically freed. Its lifetime will be extended until a `free` call, whereas `temp` in your example has a limited lifetime (block).